# Получение фотографий пользователей (photos.getAll) VK на Android

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Проблема заключается в том, что VKList все время пуст (NullPointerException).
Документация ВК говорит, что команда `photos.getAll` должна возвращать список объектов типа `photo`

```
  `VKRequest request = new VKRequest("photos.getAll", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, 1));
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            VKList list = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Кол-во фоток: "+ list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });`
```

Каким способом решить эту проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо было указать родительский класс массива **VKPhotoArray.class**;

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("photos.getAll", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, 1), VKPhotoArray.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом проверьте подключили вы права "PHOTOS".
Также надо посмотреть правильно ли вы указали Owned_id (id пользователя или сообщества, у которой нужно взять все фотографии). В Вашем коде стоит 1 - это не правильно.

Comment: Права на фотографии есть - 

`private String[] scope = {VKScope.FRIENDS, VKScope.PHOTOS};`, а `owner_id = 1` это id Павла Дурова, для примера вставил

Comment: а вообще подключение происходит к Вконтакте, получаете токен? И я бы все равно попробовал, owner_id поставить какой-нибудь более реальный, например свой.

Comment: Да я пробовал другие owner_id.
Список друзей получаю.
А вот с фотографиями беда