# Как правильно сформировать запрос на получение фотографий пользователя через VK Api для Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, vkontakte-api, android-sdk, android-vksdk

Проблема в следующем: не обрабатывается листенером запрос на получение фотографий пользователя. Т.е он его просто пропускает. При замене запроса на получение данных о юзере листенер реагирует и все обрабатывает (дебагер заходит в onComplete() и я могу видеть что в строке str). 
Код запроса:

```
//VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, UserId, VKApiConst.FIELDS, "counters, connections,contacts,site"));
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("photos.getAll", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID,UserId), VKPhotoArray.class);
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        String str = response.json.toString();
    }
});
```

Так понимаю что проблема в посторении запроса на получение фотографий. Как тогда правильно сформировать запрос?
Пример был взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530321/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-photos-getall-vk-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android).

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким образом попробуйте

```
        VKRequest request = new VKRequest("photos.getAll", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.PHOTO_SIZES, 1, VKApiConst.OFFSET, offset));
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: вот посмотрите мой репозиторий https://github.com/pavel163/VKPhoto. Я  там работаю как раз с фотками из вк